# SystemTap seems to give unrelevant output

Tags: linux, kernel, trace, systemtap

My system is Ubuntu, `uname -r = 4.15.0-23-generic`. I've installed debug symbols for a kernel.

My problem is:

---

> I am trying to use `socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)` for transmision
>   purpose. For `sendto(fd, 0,0,0,0,0)` syscall I've got `EINVAL`
>   (Invalid Argument) and I am trying to investigate what the cause is.

---

Therefore, to find out what returns `EINVAL` I am using the SystemTap. The script below tracks execution statement by statement of `tpacket_snd` function.

**my probe program: info.stp**

```
probe kernel.statement("tpacket_snd@*:*") {
    tokenize(pp(),"@");
    printf("HIT %s\n", tokenize("","@"))
}
```

And here is the output of `sudo stap info.stp` for my implementation of that kind of transmission:

```
HIT /build/linux-uT8zSN/linux-4.15.0/net/packet/af_packet.c:2619")
HIT /build/linux-uT8zSN/linux-4.15.0/net/packet/af_packet.c:2627")
HIT /build/linux-uT8zSN/linux-4.15.0/net/packet/af_packet.c:2628")
HIT /build/linux-uT8zSN/linux-4.15.0/net/packet/af_packet.c:2636")
HIT /build/linux-uT8zSN/linux-4.15.0/net/packet/af_packet.c:2638")
HIT /build/linux-uT8zSN/linux-4.15.0/net/packet/af_packet.c:2640")
HIT /build/linux-uT8zSN/linux-4.15.0/net/packet/af_packet.c:2641")
HIT /build/linux-uT8zSN/linux-4.15.0/net/packet/af_packet.c:2656")
HIT /build/linux-uT8zSN/linux-4.15.0/net/packet/af_packet.c:2659")
HIT /build/linux-uT8zSN/linux-4.15.0/net/packet/af_packet.c:2658")
HIT /build/linux-uT8zSN/linux-4.15.0/net/packet/af_packet.c:2662")
HIT /build/linux-uT8zSN/linux-4.15.0/net/packet/af_packet.c:2663")
HIT /build/linux-uT8zSN/linux-4.15.0/net/packet/af_packet.c:2669")
HIT /build/linux-uT8zSN/linux-4.15.0/net/packet/af_packet.c:2671")
HIT /build/linux-uT8zSN/linux-4.15.0/net/packet/af_packet.c:2674")
HIT /build/linux-uT8zSN/linux-4.15.0/net/packet/af_packet.c:2672")
HIT /build/linux-uT8zSN/linux-4.15.0/net/packet/af_packet.c:2675")
HIT /build/linux-uT8zSN/linux-4.15.0/net/packet/af_packet.c:2680")
HIT /build/linux-uT8zSN/linux-4.15.0/net/packet/af_packet.c:2688")
HIT /build/linux-uT8zSN/linux-4.15.0/net/packet/af_packet.c:2692")
HIT /build/linux-uT8zSN/linux-4.15.0/net/packet/af_packet.c:2694")
HIT /build/linux-uT8zSN/linux-4.15.0/net/packet/af_packet.c:2693")
HIT /build/linux-uT8zSN/linux-4.15.0/net/packet/af_packet.c:2706")
HIT /build/linux-uT8zSN/linux-4.15.0/net/packet/af_packet.c:2710")
HIT /build/linux-uT8zSN/linux-4.15.0/net/packet/af_packet.c:2707")
HIT /build/linux-uT8zSN/linux-4.15.0/net/packet/af_packet.c:2708")
HIT /build/linux-uT8zSN/linux-4.15.0/net/packet/af_packet.c:2709")
HIT /build/linux-uT8zSN/linux-4.15.0/net/packet/af_packet.c:2712")
HIT /build/linux-uT8zSN/linux-4.15.0/net/packet/af_packet.c:2743")
HIT /build/linux-uT8zSN/linux-4.15.0/net/packet/af_packet.c:2728")
HIT /build/linux-uT8zSN/linux-4.15.0/net/packet/af_packet.c:2736")
HIT /build/linux-uT8zSN/linux-4.15.0/net/packet/af_packet.c:2735")
HIT /build/linux-uT8zSN/linux-4.15.0/net/packet/af_packet.c:2785")
HIT /build/linux-uT8zSN/linux-4.15.0/net/packet/af_packet.c:2787")
HIT /build/linux-uT8zSN/linux-4.15.0/net/packet/af_packet.c:2789")
```

[https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15/source/net/packet/af_packet.c#L2618]

---

My question is:
That output is unrelevant (doesn't match to) with sourcecode, because:

1. Firstly,
   it is pointed that line af_packet.c:`2707` was executed after `2710`
   `2710` contains no jump instruction.

---

2. Secondly,
   From my investigation I could conlude that condition: [lines 2741-2745]

   if (po->has_vnet_hdr && virtio_net_hdr_to_skb(skb, vnet_hdr,          vio_le())) {
       tp_len = -EINVAL;
       goto tpacket_error;
   }

   was evaluated to the true- note that SystemTap points that line 2743 was executed. But, from the other side I've investigated  with SystemTap that `po->has_vnet_hdr` is equal to 0 so it is not possible to execute if body. However, SystemTap points it.

My question is:

How to repair it or what do I wrongly?

Comment: My initial reaction is that this is just compiler output with optimizations.  There is no guarantee that the underlying assembler ordering will match the source code.

Comment: For `SOCK_DGRAM` sockets, you must specify a destination address at every `sendto()`. Passing `NULL, 0` for addr, addr_len is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Q1: Peter is quite right.  After compiler optimizations, the source lines may appear to be executed in non-linear sequence, as the instructions of different C statements are intermingled.  This does not represent a problem.

Q2: To figure out which statement caused the -EINVAL return, I would combine statement probes (like you have, except also printing `$$vars` to see the local variables) **AND** a function `.call`/`.return` probe pair, to note when the function is being left.  The last few statement trace lines before the return would be where I'd look for the cause.